# What is the best way to persist SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I am developing an application which mimics in someways as notebook. The users login in to the web application, connect to the data-source(database/csv) and then write series of SQL queries. These are typically queries used to compute metrics.

The workflow subsequently is to run these queries on periodic basis to compute the metrics and persist them as time-series data.

Since the users can write SQL queries here, what would be the suggested approach to persist the query in a backend store?

Comment: `Since the users can write SQL queries here,` ... you're going to have to ensure that your users cannot enter malicious SQL.

Comment: Agreed. Is there any good way to achieve them. I have seen some applications do this, where they allow users to define SQL queries. SQL provides easy way to express the full query unlike any other UI driven builder.

Comment: You could only allow those user queries to execute under a MySQL user with read only access.  That would be a start.

Comment: Agreed. One approach I can see is using templating like Jinja and persisting them outside SQL like on file storage.

Comment: As for persisting those queries: the users are entering them as *text* (I assume), so you can also *store* them as text

Answer (score 0):

You can store SQL queries as text.

But you must not allow users to define SQL queries and then run them verbatim, without first having a human vet the query to make sure it's not malicious (or even simply errors or unwise queries).